# ElasticSearch bulk API using JS SDK

Tags: elasticsearch

I have this call:

```
  const lst = [];  // an array with a few object in it 

  c.bulk({
    index: 'foo',
    body: lst.map(v => JSON.stringify(v)).join('\n')
  })
   .catch(e => {
     log.error(e);
   });
```

I am trying to insert multiple items into ES. The bulk API is here:
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/api-reference.html

but for some reason with the above call I get this error:

> ResponseError: illegal_argument_exception   at
>   IncomingMessage.
>   (/Users/alex/codes/interos/@interos/elastic-search/node_modules/@elastic/elasticsearch/lib/Transport.js:287:25)
>   at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:15)   at endReadableNT
>   (_stream_readable.js:1154:12)   at processTicksAndRejections
>   (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)

I tried using this:

```
  c.bulk({
    method: 'POST',
    index: 'foo',
    body: lst.map(v => JSON.stringify(v)).join('\n') + '\n'
  })
   .catch(e => {
     log.error(e);
   });
```

used `method:POST` and ensured there was a newline at the end of the body, still the same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the [JS bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/javascript-api/current/bulk_examples.html) you don't need to stringify anything and most importantly you're missing the command lines before each object you want to index.

Your `body` should be constructed like this instead:

```
const body = lst.flatMap(doc => [{ index: { _index: 'foo' } }, doc])

c.bulk({
  index: 'foo',
  body: body
})
.catch(e => {
  log.error(e);
});
```